# Causal AR Model?

Tags: regression-coefficients, causality, autoregressive, bounds

This questions is about necessary conditions (in form of inequality on coefficients) for the causality of autoregressive models.  For instance, $|\phi_1| < 1$ is a necessary condition for an AR(1) model to be causal, or $|\phi_1| < 2$ and $|\phi_2| < 1$ are two necessary conditions for an AR(2) model to be causal. Shall we have such inequalities for an AR(p) model in general? If so, please provide a reference. Thanks.

P.S. I am not looking for a sufficient condition, a necessary condition is good enough.